# RVIZ - robot model status error for Clearpath Jackal

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the rviz jackal simulation. However, I get this status error. The simulation environment is empty, I couldn't see the jackal robot. I have added the image below. Could anyone help?
[image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9wJJ585u_B7dG1rRVFWRm1mSW8)

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252448/rviz---robot-model-status-error-for-clearpath-jackal/) by [spalania](https://answers.ros.org/users/29119/spalania/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-01-19

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry my bad. I should have run the gazebo and then the rviz.

---

Originally posted by [spalania](https://answers.ros.org/users/29119/spalania/) with karma: 36 on 2017-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1